# What's the standard format for assignment expressions?

Tags: javascript, standards, jslint

I have the following function in JavaScript and when running it through JSLint, it yelled at me, as I call it.

```
function getPos(event, element) {
    var x = event.clientX,
        y = event.clientY,
        currentElement = element;

    do {
        x -= currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
        y -= currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
    } while ((currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent));

    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}
```

Specifically about the inline assignment expression in the while loop. I figured the double parentheses was the standard way of saying, "I'm expecting the returned value from the assignment expression to be type-casted to a `Boolean` for the conditional." JSLint seems to disagree, even when I enable "assignment expressions." Then I tried adding a `!!` in front, and JSLint complains that it's "confusing usage." So my question is, what's the right way of formatting this?

**EDIT:** By "this", I meant specifically the inline assignment expression. The intent of my question was to clarify what an acceptable standard for that particular line was, if one really wanted to use that, and though I do agree that thefourtheye's answer is the most correct way to write the function, it is not the answer to the question I was asking.

Comment: There was a version of Opera some time ago that required the double parenthesis when doing assignment as a condition, otherwise it would "correct" the assignment to `==`.

Comment: @RobG Eheh, I bet developers just loved debugging _that_ one~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](https://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-assignment-expression), for JSHint, ESHint and JSLint (from before July 2013) you can force it into a conditional like this:

```
do {
  // ...
} while ((currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent) !== null);
```

For more recent versions of JSLint you're out of luck and you need to separate out your assignment if you value the all green.

Comment: Wouldn't it be ``undefined`` instead of ``null`` in that case, then?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent) it may be `null`, assuming it's a `HTMLElement` of course.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. Nice answer.

Comment: Though, it's possible that `offsetParent` itself is not defined, in which case you need to test *that* first :)

Comment: It will be defined, the application itself assumes an HTML5 compliant browser anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to have assignment expressions in conditional expressions. But, I believe that `while` would suit this case better than `do...while`. You could transform the code to this

```
function getPos(event, element) {
    var x = event.clientX,
        y = event.clientY,
        currentElement = element;

    while (currentElement) {
        x -= currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
        y -= currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
        currentElement = element.offsetParent;
    }

    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}
```

Now, there is no assignment involved in the conditional expression and I believe this looks clean.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I like how you propose to make the code cleaner by changing the control flow. However if I were to nit-pick, this doesn't _really_ answer the question, because I asked for the correct format for the inline assignment expression.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I understood your question, that is why I started with a sugguestion :) Personally, I would not use assignment expression in place of a conditional expression.

Comment: Why bother with *currentElement* at all? Why not: `while (element) { ...; element = element.offsetParent}`. I don't see *element* being used for anything else, nor is it modified before entering the loop.

Comment: @RobG I have the habit of naming the looping variable as `current...` if I am iterating a collection. OP had similar structure, so I didn't want to change it.

Comment: @RobG I don't know if it's a valid reason to do so, but personally I've sort of come to think of editing function arguments as a bad habit to get into, unless of course an in-place function is the intention.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts—some don't like reusing variables, I get that. But then introducing a new variable from habit doesn't make a lot of sense either. Each to their own. ;-)